# How to group items under a category?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm trying to print out "nicely" results from a database query. I have categories (cities) and items (people) in them.

My goal is this:

```
New York
    John
    Peter
    Glenn
Los Angeles
    Annie
    Ben
    Norman
```

Each city and people name needs to be a link to a details document. I already tried GROUP_CONCAT but it did not work out the way I wanted. I'm also hesitating which way I should query for information; First the cities and then JOIN people or vice versa?

Comment: This type of manipulation is best done at the application layer -- that is, in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to do it in this simple query assuming your table structure is like this

```
id| People| City
```

And the Code is

```
 <?php

    $stmt = $pdo-> query("SELECT * FROM `YourTable` ORDER BY City");

    $current_cat = null;
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      if ($row["City"] != $current_cat) {
        $current_cat = $row["City"];
        echo "Category #{$current_cat}\n";
      }
      echo $row["People"] . "\n";
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you have a foreign key in people table that points to the city you can query as follows:

```
select c.cityname,p.name from city c left join people p on c.cityid=p.peopleid
order by c.cityid
```

in this way you will query all cities even though there is no people in it

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a foreign key...

Comment: you must have a foreign key so try restructuring your tables